# Löve 2D parando de responder ao iniciar | Lua

Tags: lua, love2d

Estou tentando utilizar Löve 2D, comecei a criar um jogo onde olhos seguem o mouse.
Mas sempre quando tento jogar o programa para de responder.
E não é só no meu código, o executável na pasta LOVE roda por alguns frames e para de responder também.
O código que fiz até aqui:

```
function love.draw()


--@ Eye position @--
  local eyeX = 250
  local eyeY = 250
  --@ Distance X and Y between eye - mouse @--
  local distanceX = love.mouse.getX() - eyeX
  local distanceY = love.mouse.getY() - eyeY
  --@ Distance (straight line) between eye - mouse @--
  local distance = math.sqrt(distanceX^2 + distanceY^2)
  
  --@ Draw eye @--
  love.graphics.setColor(1, 1, 1)
  love.graphics.circle("fill", eyeX, eyeY, 75)
  --@ Draw pupil @--
  love.graphics.setColor(0, .5, 1)
  love.graphics.circle("fill", 250, 250, 25)
  --@ Print values @--
  love.graphics.setColor(1, 1, 1)
  love.graphics.print(table.concat({
  'Distance X: ' ..distanceX,
  'Distance Y: ' ..distanceY
  }, '\n'))
end
```

O resultado: Ele desenha um olho e printa umas informações, mas logo para de responder.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como tinha falado, o problema não é só no meu código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou reinstalar? Tem acesso a algum log? Se tiver, poste-o na pergunta

Comment: Já, não tenho. .

Comment: Bom eu fiz mais alguns testes e descobri que o problema está especificamente nas funções de desenho, tipo love.graphics.circle("fill", eyeX, eyeY, 75)

Comment: agora porque eu não sei